# How to get first significant figure from a number in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, significant-digits

I have a column of numbers in Excel 2016. The numbers span many orders of magnitude, but are all positive. Some are less than zero. How can I return the first significant figure of each cell in a new column?

For example, for the number 1.9 the result should be 1. For the number 0.9 the result should be 9.

Things I've tried:

- Using `LEFT()` to get the first character. This works for values greater than 1, but for numbers between 0 - 1 it returns 0 (that is, `LEFT(0.3, 1)` returns 0). I've tried using this with scientific notation formatting and it returns the same result.
- I've searched Google and SO for solutions to this problem. There are many posts about rounding to significant figures, but I'm looking to truncate, not round.
- Reading through Office's online docs regarding scientific notation.

Comment: `=LEFT(0.3*10000,1)`

Comment: What about `0.003` would it still be `3`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use scientific notation:

```
=LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0.000000000000000E+00"))
```

[image]

Note: You can only have 15 digits of precision in Excel so this should be OK.

Comment: It seems that using "0.0E+00" is also working. Good solution! `=--LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0.0E+00"))`

Comment: Thanks! I was concerned that in the case of 2.9999999 it might round up to 3 if I didn't put enough zeroes, but of course you still find a number like 2.99999999999 that will eventually round up.

Answer (score 2):

you can multiply the number by a factor of 10 significant enough to deal with any `0` not wanted:

```
=--LEFT(A1*10^LEN(A1),1)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: +1. Thanks for posting this as an answer. This definitely works, but it requires knowing what order of magnitude the smallest value is. I'm hoping for a solution that works regardless what order of magnitude the values are.

Comment: @indigochild see edit, now it will not matter.  The multiplier will be big enough regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Read the cell value as text, replace dots and zeros (`.` / `0`) with nothing, return the leftmost "character"; multiply it by 1 to coerce it back into a number:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"@"),".",""),"0",""))*1
```

Comment: Hi David your idea is pretty good and I modified the formula a bit and it still worked `=--LEFT(--SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""),1)`, no need to replace `0` just need to get rid of `.` and convert the new string to number and look for the first number on left.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom UDF (User Defined Function) that uses Regular Expressions to accomplish this task. This would require copy/paste VBA knowledge, as well as you setting a reference to:

> Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

<sup>*(which can be done by going to the VBE (Alt+F11), Tools > References. Then check the box of the reference listed above)*</sup>

Paste the following UDF into a standard code module within the VBE:

```vb
Public Function SigNum(ByVal InputNumber As Double) As Long

    Dim s As SubMatches

    With New RegExp

        .Pattern = "\.0*([^0])|^([^0])"
        If .test(InputNumber) Then

            Set s = .Execute(InputNumber)(0).SubMatches
            If s(0) > 0 Then    ' This is before the period
                SigNum = s(0)
            Else
                SigNum = s(1)
            End If

        End If

    End With

End Function
```

On your worksheet, you would be able to use your newly created formula as such:

```
=SigNum(A1)
```

You can see what it matches in the example on **[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OfeAUN/2)**. *When viewing this site, green highlighted numbers are what would be returned if the value is < 0, and red would be what is returned if the value > 0)*. If the value = 0, this will return 0.

---

### Breaking Down the Pattern

Here's how the pattern `\.0*([^0])|^([^0])` works. First, you can see that there is a `|`, which essentially acts like an `Or` statement, so we will split these into two sections.

#### First Section `\.0*([^0])`

- `\.` will match a literal period. This ensures that we are looking at a value that is less than 0.
- `0*` matches all zeros, 0 to unlimited `*` times. We use `*` (zero to unlimited) instead of `+` (1 to unlimited) because a zero is not required to be in front of the significant number - but the zero itself *isn't* significant.
- `[^0]` This is a negated character class `[^...]`. This means it will match anything that *is not* in this class. Since our significant number should be a value other than zero, we do not want to match a zero. And because it's surrounded by a capturing group `(...)`, this is what is returned back to the function.

#### Second Section `^([^0])`

We've established that since the first section didn't match, then the value must be greater than 0.

- `^` this is an anchor point that matches the beginning of the string. On the first section we didn't require it because we essentially used the period `\.` as our anchor. Since our value is greater than 0, we need to ensure we are starting from the absolute left of the input number.
- `(...)` Capturing Group. Anything within this group will be returned as a submatch and ultimately back to the function as it's return value.
- `[^0]` Negated Character class. It will match anything except a 0.